# make email optional in magento 2 and login is working through mobile

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a Magento 2.3.4 installation and I wish to convert the e-mail field to be non-required, and i have already made the phone number instead.  I have searched in the source code, there are so many places are using field email, and as it's validation.
Mobile login is working fine for me ,i just want to make email optional so that customers can place order without email using phone

Comment: Did you work it out? @andrew-smith

Comment: not yet...i tried many possible ways but unfortunetly got issues only